# Logstash--Dynamic indexes on the basis of fields set in logstash forwarder

Tags: logstash

I want to create indexes from values of 'Application' field which I set in logstash-forwarder on client machine.
For example: 
in logstash-forwarder.conf on CRM client, I write

```
{
"paths": [
"/var/log/crm/crmERROR.log"
],
"fields": {**"**Application**":"CRM"**,"Sub-System":"Mysystem", "type":"Error-logs "
}

in LSF config on sales client 2 I say 
{
"paths": [
"/var/log/sales/SalesERROR.log"
],
"fields": {**"Application":"Sales"**,"Sub-System":"Myststem", "type":"Error-logs "
}
```

all those logs will be sent to redis through LS-shipper. LS-indexer will pick it up from redis.
Now in LS-Indexer, I want to create indexes on the basis of values of field  "Application" (CRM,Sales). How Can I get these values of Application field so that I can use it in output to create indexname.

br,
Sunil.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The elasticsearch{} output allow you to [specify the index name](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index), e.g.:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

You can use variables in the index name:

```
index => "%{my_field}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
```

Comment: Thanks! I already done that and its working. Even if its late but the correct answer :)

Comment: @Alain: Is this required %{+YYYY.MM.dd} when creating indexing? (I'm currently learn ES)

Comment: @sk8terboi87ツ, that extra bit on the parameter specifies that you want the date (from @timestamp) appended to the index name, giving you a daily index.  If you wanted a monthly index (etc), you could use a different pattern; if you wanted a single index, you could use a constant.  Typically, you want to stick with daily indexes for log files.

Comment: @AlainCollins: Thank you! So, it means, indexing daily will improve searching the log?

Comment: Daily indexes are convenient because you can adjust your shard/replica count if needed, you can have a daily retention policy (expire after 21 days, etc), etc.  There will be more overhead in elasticsearch to keep those indexes/shards open.